# Why <text> inside my svg is NOT being displayed

Tags: css, svg, d3.js

I have a bar chart with a text element inside svg, as shown in the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/447dpk2o/

```
<svg id="someChart" width="1000" height="300" data-reactid=".0.1.0" style="background-color: aliceblue;">
<text id="charDisplay" x="50" y="50" style="">My TEXT
</text>
<rect class="bar" x="0" width="31" y="270" height="30"></rect>
<rect class="bar" x="35" width="31" y="285" height="15"></rect>
<rect class="bar" x="70" width="31" y="285" height="15"></rect>
<rect class="bar" x="105" width="31" y="240" height="60"></rect>
<rect class="bar" x="140" width="31" y="255" height="45"></rect>
<rect class="bar" x="175" width="31" y="270" height="30"></rect>
<rect class="bar" x="210" width="31" y="285" height="15"></rect>
<rect class="bar" x="245" width="31" y="285" height="15"></rect>
<rect class="bar" x="280" width="31" y="285" height="15"></rect>
<rect class="bar" x="315" width="31" y="270" height="30"></rect>
```

My text is not being displayed at all. I am not sure why. I am little new to SVG moreover this elements have been created using d3. But I am sure this has nothing to do with my d3 code.

Please help!!!

Comment: Because you've set the color to white! http://jsfiddle.net/447dpk2o/1/

Answer (score 2):

It's the `fill: white;` on `#someChart text` that does it. Change the color and it should work.

```
#someChart text {
  fill: black; /*Changed from white */
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  text-anchor: middle;
}
```